# Define method in init

Tags: python, class, oop, object, init

I want to have a class with an `__iter__` method that depends on a `cache` argument when instances are created.

If an instance is created with `cache=False`, then the instance should be iterated through like a generator (creating and discarding each item as needed). If an instance is created with `cache=True`, then the object should create a list of the items, store it, and then have it available to be iterated through repeatedly.

So for example (this doesn't work):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, max=5, cache=False):
        if cache:
            self.items = range(max)
            self.__iter__ = iter(self.items)
        else:
            self.__iter__ = iter(range(max))
```

Then if I did this, the expected result is to print 0--4, and to have this available only once.

```
 test_obj = Foo()
 for i in test_obj:
     print i, # 0 1 2 3 4
 for i in test_obj:
     print i, # empty
```

But if I do this, the expected result is to print 0--4, and to have this available as many times as necessary.

```
test_obj = Foo(cache=True)
for i in test_obj:
    print i, # 0 1 2 3 4
for i in test_obj:
    print i, # 0 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python won't look up a `__op__` method on an instance, only on a class. So your idea of defining `__iter__` from `__init__` won't work. However, you can implement `__iter__` such that its behavior differs dending on a value set in `__init__`. Here's one way:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, max=5, cache=False):
        if cache:
            self.iterable = range(max)
        else:
            self.iterable = iter(xrange(max))

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.iterable)
```

This works because an iterator is "iterable" just like a sequence is. However, its `__iter__` method returns itself (so no matter how many times you can `iter` on it, you can only iterate through its values once).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach it - if it's not cached, discard `self.items` the first time `__iter__` is called:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, max_=5, cached=False):
        self.items = range(max_)
        self._cached = cache

    def __iter__(self):
        out = self.items
        if not self._cached:
            self.items = []
        return iter(out)
```

In action:

```
>>> test_obj = Foo()
>>> for i in test_obj:
    print i,


0 1 2 3 4
>>> for i in test_obj:
    print i,


>>> test_obj = Foo(cached=True)
>>> for i in test_obj:
    print i,


0 1 2 3 4
>>> for i in test_obj:
    print i,


0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks! But one of the issues is actually that self.items will be very large, and I want to avoid storing it in the instance unless the user plans to use it over and over again.

Comment: I see what you mean - edited, it will now discard `self.items` the first time `__iter__` is called if it isn't `_cached`.